# Compiling Bootstrap 5 sass in Vaadin 8 project fails

Tags: sass, vaadin, bootstrap-5, vaadin8

I would like to use the [Bootstrap 5 sass utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/) in my Vaadin 8 project (to help facilitate using flexbox layouts, responsive layouts, and writing custom css). However, when I include the Bootstrap scss files I get a generic compilation error when importing the Bootstrap _functions.scss:

> Compiling theme "VAADIN/themes/mytheme" failed (com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-
> plugin:8.14.3:compile-theme:default:generate-resources)

In the details it just says that the com.vaadin.sass.SassCompiler "failed with status 1".

When I remove the code from _functions.scss and add it back bit by bit, it seems to be dying on the @each line of a mixin definition.  I am assuming this is because the sass compiler is old?  So my questions are:

1. Are there logs or something where I can see the actual error that occurred when compiling the scss?
2. How can I update the sass compiler in my Vaadin 8 project?
3. Has anyone else successfully compiled the bootstrap sass in their Vaadin 8 project, and if so, how?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I commented out the compile-theme line like so:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
             <configuration>
                <theme>mytheme</theme>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- 2022-10-13 Commenting out compile-theme and using sass-maven-plugin to compile modern sass instead -->
                        <!-- <goal>compile-theme</goal> --> 
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And added the sass-maven-plugin like so:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>nl.geodienstencentrum.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <source>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/scss</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.scss</include>
                            </includes>
                        </source>
                        <relativeOutputDirectory>..</relativeOutputDirectory>
                        <destination>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme</destination>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-stylesheets</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I had to copy the [valo source code](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/tree/master/themes/src/main/themes/VAADIN/themes/valo) into my themes folder (since the Vaadin sass compiler was pulling it from the jar) and also the [Bootstrap 5 scss code](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/#source-files) to my themes folder.  Now my scss appears to compile (**Yay!**) BUT every time I change the scss code it seems to recompile three times and sometimes even goes into an infinite loop! (as seen in the Eclipse Console->Maven Console):

```
2022-10-13, 9:21:24 p.m. EDT: [WARN] The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2
2022-10-13, 9:21:24 p.m. EDT: [WARN] The POM for com.amazon.paapi:paapi5-java-sdk:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
2022-10-13, 9:21:24 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Resolving P/newsys.orm: com.librarybound:newsys.orm:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT with classifier  to /newsys.orm/target/classes
2022-10-13, 9:21:24 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Resolving P/cxfwebservices: com.librarybound:cxfwebservices:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT with classifier  to /cxfwebservices/target/classes
2022-10-13, 9:21:24 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Updating theme VAADIN/themes/mytheme
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Widgetsets found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO]    org.tepi.imageviewer.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/Susan/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/imageviewer/0.6.0.v8/imageviewer-0.6.0.v8.jar!/
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Addon styles found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] 
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Search took 38ms
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Theme "VAADIN/themes/mytheme" updated
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Checked 0 files for C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\src\main\sass
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Checked 1 filtered (**/*.css) files for C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\target\web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\css
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Compiling Sass templates
2022-10-13, 9:21:26 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Queueing Sass template for compile: C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/scss => C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme
2022-10-13, 9:21:55 p.m. EDT: [INFO]     >> C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/scss/styles.scss => C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css
2022-10-13, 9:21:55 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
2022-10-13, 9:21:55 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Copying 0 resource
2022-10-13, 9:21:55 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
2022-10-13, 9:21:55 p.m. EDT: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\src\test\resources
2022-10-13, 9:21:55 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Updating theme VAADIN/themes/mytheme
2022-10-13, 9:21:57 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Widgetsets found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:21:57 p.m. EDT: [INFO]    org.tepi.imageviewer.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/Susan/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/imageviewer/0.6.0.v8/imageviewer-0.6.0.v8.jar!/
2022-10-13, 9:21:57 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Addon styles found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:21:57 p.m. EDT: [INFO] 
2022-10-13, 9:21:57 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Search took 46ms
2022-10-13, 9:21:58 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Theme "VAADIN/themes/mytheme" updated
2022-10-13, 9:21:58 p.m. EDT: [WARN] GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found.
2022-10-13, 9:21:58 p.m. EDT: [INFO] No widgetsets found - generating AppWidgetset if necessary.
2022-10-13, 9:21:58 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Updating widgetset AppWidgetset
2022-10-13, 9:21:58 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Adding resource directory to command classpath: C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\src\main\resources
2022-10-13, 9:21:58 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Adding resource directory to command classpath: C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\target\generated-resources\gwt
2022-10-13, 9:21:58 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.14.3
2022-10-13, 9:21:58 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.14.3
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Widgetsets found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO]    org.tepi.imageviewer.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/Susan/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/imageviewer/0.6.0.v8/imageviewer-0.6.0.v8.jar!/
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO]    com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/Susan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/8.14.3/vaadin-client-8.14.3.jar!/
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Addon styles found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO] 
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Search took 30ms
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Checked 0 files for C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\src\main\sass
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Checked 1 filtered (**/*.css) files for C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\target\web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\css
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Compiling Sass templates
2022-10-13, 9:21:59 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Queueing Sass template for compile: C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/scss => C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO]     >> C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/scss/styles.scss => C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] auto discovered modules [AppWidgetset]
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.14.3
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.14.3
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] AppWidgetset is up to date. GWT compilation skipped
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\src\test\resources
2022-10-13, 9:22:31 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Updating theme VAADIN/themes/mytheme
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Widgetsets found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO]    org.tepi.imageviewer.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/Susan/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/imageviewer/0.6.0.v8/imageviewer-0.6.0.v8.jar!/
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Addon styles found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] 
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Search took 42ms
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Theme "VAADIN/themes/mytheme" updated
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [WARN] GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found.
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] No widgetsets found - generating AppWidgetset if necessary.
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Updating widgetset AppWidgetset
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Adding resource directory to command classpath: C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\src\main\resources
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Adding resource directory to command classpath: C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\target\generated-resources\gwt
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.14.3
2022-10-13, 9:22:33 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.14.3
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Widgetsets found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO]    org.tepi.imageviewer.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/Susan/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/imageviewer/0.6.0.v8/imageviewer-0.6.0.v8.jar!/
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO]    com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/Susan/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/8.14.3/vaadin-client-8.14.3.jar!/
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Addon styles found from classpath:
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO] 
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Search took 40ms
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Checked 0 files for C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\src\main\sass
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Checked 1 filtered (**/*.css) files for C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\target\web-1.0-SNAPSHOT\css
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Compiling Sass templates
2022-10-13, 9:22:34 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Queueing Sass template for compile: C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/scss => C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO]     >> C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/scss/styles.scss => C:/dev/lbi/dev/git/newsys/web/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] auto discovered modules [AppWidgetset]
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.14.3
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.14.3
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] AppWidgetset is up to date. GWT compilation skipped
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
2022-10-13, 9:23:07 p.m. EDT: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev\lbi\dev\git\newsys\web\src\test\resources
```

Am I doing this correctly?  And how can I make it NOT recompile a million times every time I change something in the .scss files?

Comment: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not a solution; but I tried this years ago and failed. The Vaadin sass parser can't handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin's own compiler does not support SASS 3. I would recommend to add 3rd party maven plugin to compile SASS files. E.g. sass-maven-plugin could work.

```
<groupId>nl.geodienstencentrum.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

You can configure it to use your theme location in the project

```
<configuration>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <source>
                <directory>${basedir}/_themepath_</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.scss</include>
                </includes>
            </source>
            <relativeOutputDirectory>..</relativeOutputDirectory>
            <destination>${basedir}/_themepath_</destination>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</configuration>
```

And just remove the compile-theme target in vaadin-plugin in your project.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to get it compiling (yay!), but I am still having some issues with it recompiling three times every time I make an edit. Please see the update on my original post for more details.